# cURL post size limitations

Tags: curl, sas

I'm calling cURL in SAS to perform POST requests.  My code runs fine except the post output (json file) gets truncated when I submit larger requests.  The maximum size of the json file is 1098304 even though I set both the --max-filesize option in cURL and lrecl in SAS equal to 10000000.  I'm running SAS 9.3 on Windows 7.  Note I need the ability to download larger json files, so simply limiting the size of the output isn't an option.  Has anyone run into this problem?  If so, how did you handle it?

Update1: Now running curl with the x command instead of filename pipe statement. The entire file gets dumped into the cmd window.  I would like the output to be stored in a text file instead.  I tried using both -o C:\json.txt  and -O C:\json.txt at at the beginning and end of the cURL command, but it doesn't work.  File gets dumped into the cmd window.  Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?  Perhaps there's another cURL command I can use?

Update2: After spending some time experimenting with the code, I discovered the "POST" text in the cURL command was unnecessary.  I removed it and everything works perfectly.  cURL dumps the entire output straight into a text file, and I can then parse the json with proc groovy.  Success!

Thanks very much to Joe, Robert, and user667489 for their helpful suggestions and analysis.

Final code:

```
x   "curl -d @C:\Users\Bill\Desktop\curl.txt -H ""Authorization: OAuth oauth_consumer_key=""""&oauth_consumer_key"""",oauth_token=""""&oauth_token"""",oauth_signature_method=""""&oauth_signature_method."""",
        oauth_signature=""""&oauth_signature."""",oauth_timestamp=""""&oauth_timestamp."""",oauth_nonce=""""&oauth_nonce."""",oauth_version=""""&oauth_version."""""" 
        -k &url. -o C:\json.txt";
```

Comment: Do you run into the same error if you run the same cURL command via a prompt / batch file?

Comment: Thanks for suggestion.  I should have done this prior to posting.  This is a SAS issue.  When I run cURL from the command line, I get the entire file.  There's no truncation.

Comment: What size is the JSON file supposed to be?

Comment: Not that large, perhaps 2-4mb in text file form.

Comment: Can you provide the data step code you are using to read it in as well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per Joe's suggestion I used an x command to run cURL and then saved the output directly to a text file.  This circumvents any restrictions in SAS.  I can then parse the json data using proc groovy.  Final cURL code is above in the first post of the thread.

Answer (score 2):

According to [Infile Statement for Microsoft Windows](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/hostwin/63047/HTML/default/viewer.htm#chifoptfmain.htm), the limit to LRECL should be 1GB (well over what you have).  However, I have in the past had issues where 1MB (1024^3) seemed to be the limit.  On the other hand, that's smaller than what you see.  As such I'm not sure I can say I know what the issue is, directly.

One possibility is that you are reading in UTF8 characters (or some other unicode variant).  In that case, the LRECL limit is probably *bytes*, not *characters*.  So I could see a reduction - depending on the unicode variant, up to 4x or so - from the maximum.  You could try `MAX` in the lrecl= field, and see what it did; hopefully not 32767 (as the LRECL system option still claims to).  Still doesn't explain the discrepancy, but a possibility to consider.  If raising from 10MB to `MAX` or 30MB or 100MB or any higher number raises the total length, then that could explain it.  I would also raise the curl maximum filesize to the same amount (or at least try raising it to something bigger) to see if some issue exists with how SAS deals with the pipe.

One thing to try might be to read it in with `RECFM=F`.  This would be in the `infile` statement when you read from the filename, I think; you could parse it in bunches of 1MB (or smaller) and deal with it that way.  You could also use a `termstr` or some other way to parse it with a delimiter, if you have such ability in your data (a common one is to use `termstr='>'` for html, for json I think `;` is common).  You don't post what your json parsing is doing, so I can't comment, but I will say that from my html parsing experience (and some json as well), it's easier to parse it when it's not gigantic lines at first.

Comment: Wow, thanks very much for your analysis, Joe.  I tried increasing both the lrecl and cURL max filesize to 1B.  Unfortunately, it didn't solve the problem.  SAS still fixes the lrecl to 1098304.  Also, I'm using proc groovy to parse the json file.  Everything is working great except when I increase the json file size.  Hmmm...I'll do some more research and will report back.  I hate to think that SAS is so limited that it can't handle records over 1M length.

Comment: BTW, since this is a SAS problem, I started a thread on sas.com.  Link: https://communities.sas.com/message/260749#260749

Comment: Is there a way to save the cURL output directly to a text file?  I tried -o C:\json.txt, but it didn't work.  If I can get the output straight into a text file from cURL then I should be able to use proc groovy to parse the data and create a SAS file.

Comment: If you run `curl` from `x` (as opposed to using a pipe), is it any different?

Comment: When I run cURL from the command line, I'm able to get the entire file.

Comment: Right, `x` is closer to the command line than pipe (I think).  If you're just using this to get the file and then use `proc groovy`, why not just use `x` to get the file (and then use `proc groovy` from that)?  Or do you need to preprocess the file before you do things to it.

Answer (score -1):

Just so you know, SAS has a max linesize of 32767, so unless the response contains multiple lines you will need to find a way to deal with that anyway. Check the length of the truncated value.  Should tell you if this is the issue.

**EDIT :** Only true for SAS 9.2 and prior apparently.  Thanks to Joe for the clarification.

Comment: Rob, this is untrue (as of 9.2 or later, at least, I don't know about earlier).  SAS has a maximum linesize *if you use _infile_* of 32767, but he'd get that as an explicit error.  Otherwise it's dependent on the OS's maximums.

Comment: Robert,  Thanks very much for your thoughts.  The response does contain multiple lines.  Each line has max length of 32759.  Total length of all the lines is 1,098,282 which is just short of the lrecl of 1,098,304.  Note I try to increase the lrecl to 10M within the filename statement.   Is there another way to increase lrecl?  Or perhaps I need to tweak another option?  Buffersize?  Thanks again.

Comment: Joe, Thanks for your thoughts.  I'm running SAS 9.3 on Windows 7 Professional.  Also, I'm dumping the output into a text file.  However, there should be no issue with the text file size.  I've created text files over 200mb.  Actually, I know this isn't the issue.  Prior to dumping the data into a text file, I put it to the sas log.  The data is truncated.

Comment: @Joe - regardless of the infile size you're still stuck with max char fields of 32767 so it's effectively the same thing.  Which, I might add, is ridiculous.

Comment: @Joe - Also, won't any warning be dependent on the truncover/flowover/missover setting on the datastep file statement?

Comment: It's not the same thing, imo; in some of this kind of parsing having a LRECL of larger is very useful.  And 9.2 definitely has higher LRECL on files ( http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/hostwin/63285/HTML/default/viewer.htm#chifoptfmain.htm )

Comment: And you get an error (not a warning) if you try to use `_INFILE_` and lrecl>32767.